# In VS, how do I prevent dlls from being copied when referenced

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, reference

I originally thought that a reference to a dll was just that, a reference.  But it appears the referenced dlls are copied to the bin\debug folder.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  It is unlikely you'll be able to debug your program unless the assembly is stored in the GAC.  In which case it wouldn't copy it.

Comment: I see.  I'm not familiar yet with using the GAC.  But something about copying dlls seems unnecessary.

Comment: Don't use the GAC.  The copy is a Good Thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right click on the reference in the solution explorer, and choose "Properties".  One of the options is "Copy Local".  Set that to false, and it won't copy the assembly.

Just realize that the assembly must still be discoverable at runtime.  This is why it copies it locally by default.

Comment: +1.  I've done this but now it won't run.  Is there a way to force it to use the dll that I've referenced to?

Comment: @user420667: No - the assembly loader uses (effectively) normal DLL discovery rules.  Unless the assembly is in the GAC, by default, it needs to be in the same folder as the .exe - which is why Copy Local is the default.  Is there a reason you don't want it to copy on build?

Comment: Well, it just seems unnecessary.  I thought the assembly loader could make use of the .sln file to help it discover the dlls.  I'm just envisioning scenarios where one solution references another which references another, which could lead to lots of needless (in my mind) copying.

Comment: @user420667: It's a feature, not a bug ;)  Its done this way to help prevent DLL-hell - you always know the version of the assembly you load is the one you used during the build, which is very nice.  The copying and file management is handled automatically by VS, so I'd just accept it (and be happy)

Comment: Ok.  I've entered unfamiliar territory and will accept the advice of the experts.